# jQuery: Showing hidden fields depending on Input [type="number"] value

Tags: jquery, user-input

i am currently working on a form where a customer can buy a ticket. When he wants to buy more than one ticket, he can change the value of the ordered tickets with an input [type="number"] field (maximum range is 5). Depending on that value some additional (formerly hidden) fields for the additional names are displayed below.

At the moment i handled this with some if/else if statements, but it doesn't "feel right" that way. Maybe anyone has a better way on the hand. And yes i am a novice on Jquery :)
Here the code i am using right now:

```
var valueNumberPicker;
var NumberPicker = $('.selectboxvaluekongress input');
var theFieldsKongress = $('.hiddenContactField');
theFieldsKongress.hide();

NumberPicker.on('change', function(){
    valueNumberPicker = NumberPicker.val();

    if (valueNumberPicker == 2){
        $('#hiddenField1').show();
    }
    else if (valueNumberPicker == 3) {
        $('#hiddenField1').show();
        $('#hiddenField2').show();
    }
    else if (valueNumberPicker == 4) {
        $('#hiddenField1').show();
        $('#hiddenField2').show();
        $('#hiddenField3').show();
    }
    else if (valueNumberPicker == 5) {
        $('#hiddenField1').show();
        $('#hiddenField2').show();
        $('#hiddenField3').show();
        $('#hiddenField4').show();
    }
});
```

Thank you

Comment: could you please share your HTML too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can narrow down your code to:

```
NumberPicker.on('change', function(){
 valueNumberPicker = NumberPicker.val();
 valueNumberPicker > 4 ? $('[id^=hiddenField]').show() : $('#hiddenField'+valueNumberPicker).show();
});
```

Comment: Nice. Worked. Thank you. But can you pls explain the "?" and the ":" sign in this context?

Comment: This is a short tag for `If..Else`, one liner.

Answer (score 2):

Above looks correct. But you can do this by writing less code as well. Something like below will works:

```
var valueNumberPicker;
var NumberPicker = $('.selectboxvaluekongress input');
var theFieldsKongress = $('.hiddenContactField');
theFieldsKongress.hide();

NumberPicker.on('change', function(){
    valueNumberPicker = NumberPicker.val();

    for(var i=1;i<valueNumberPicker;i++) {
        $('#hiddenField' + i).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice. Worked also :). Thank you too

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code:

```
NumberPicker.on('change', function(){
 valueNumberPicker = NumberPicker.val();
    for (var i = 1;i<=valueNumberPicker ;i++)
    {
    var id = "#hiddenField"+i;
    $(id).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: As OP code I think you should use just <  instead of  <=

Comment: Worked also for the third :). Thank you too

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef, nope because what if the `valueNumberPicker = 1` then the loop will not even execute, if it would have been 0 then your condition would have been right

Answer (score -1):

NumberPicker.on('change', function(){
    valueNumberPicker = NumberPicker.val();

```
if (valueNumberPicker == 2){
    $('#hiddenField1').prop("type", "Number");
}
else if (valueNumberPicker == 3) {
    $('#hiddenField1').prop("type", "Number");
    $('#hiddenField2').prop("type", "Number");
}
else if (valueNumberPicker == 4) {
    $('#hiddenField1').prop("type", "Number");
    $('#hiddenField2').prop("type", "Number");
    $('#hiddenField3').prop("type", "Number");
}
else if (valueNumberPicker == 5) {
    $('#hiddenField1').prop("type", "Number");
    $('#hiddenField2').prop("type", "Number");
    $('#hiddenField3').prop("type", "Number");
    $('#hiddenField4').prop("type", "Number");
}
```

});